# Efficient way to find all possible combinations of elements in a list which add up to a target

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, data-structures

I have got a situation where I need to find all possible combinations of numbers in a list which when added equals to a target. For example consider a list - (4,6,10,20,30,40) and target = 20. So possible combinations are (4,6,10) and (20).

Few optimizations I've considered are:

- Ignore all items in the list which are > target
- Add all numbers in the list and if the sum <= target then
   If sum=target then return the entire list(as this will be the only combination that when added equals the target)
   else sum can't be determined from the numbers in the list.
- Proceed to find all subsets from the list which when added equals the target.

The above logic works fine for smaller lists (size not greater than 10). But in the worst case scenario say the list has up to 100 elements then I need to look into 2^100 possible combinations (this may also cause integer overflows for the counter keeping track of the number of subsets) and this will slow down the program. Computing subsets will be O(2^n) n=size of the list and order of growth is exponential.

Is there a better way to tackle this problem for larger lists? I'm looking for a generic approach to solve this problem without using any language specific features. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Look for `dynamic programming` approach for `subset-sum problem`

Comment: @MBo Thanks for the suggestion. Can DP approach work if the list has fractions and target is also a fraction?

Comment: Only for case when rational values might be scaled to integers (1.33, 3.1 => 133, 310 )

Comment: Thanks @MBo. I got the idea. In my case, all the fractions are 2 decimal points. I can multiply them by 100 and then divide by it to get the result. I'll try this approach.